# AFNetworking 3 or 4.01 migration

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-3, afhttpsessionmanager

I was on AFnetworging 2.0.6 and I would like to migrate to 3 or 4.0.1.

I have problem with this part of code
I know AFHTTPRequestOperation it's not reuse on version 3 or 4.
and I have some error here.

Can you help me please.

```
    - (void)succeedWithOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)succeedOperation method:(NSString *)method
{
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if (succeedOperation.response) {
        data[@"code"] = @([succeedOperation.response statusCode]);
    }
    if (succeedOperation.responseData) {
        data[@"rawResponse"] = [succeedOperation.responseData copy];
    }
    if (succeedOperation.responseString) {
        data[@"stringResponse"] = [succeedOperation.responseString copy];
    }
```

error like ==> Property 'response' not found on object of type '__strong id'

If I change AFHTTPRequestOperation by AFHTTPSessionManager or NSURLSessionDataTask I have

No visible @interface for 'NSURLResponse' declares the selector 'statusCode' ...

Thank for your help.